# How to create memory segment with fixed size, place data in fixed position inside the segment, using MinGW

Tags: c, linker, mingw

I am using MinGW to create a win32 exe.
I would like to create a memory segment with a fixed size, and after that place variable inside this segment at a fixed address relative to the start of the segment. Has anyone an idea of how to do this?

I was able to declare my own segment with:

```
  .codeflash BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    __codeflash_start__ = . ;
    *(.codeflash)
    __codeflash_end__ = . ;    
  }
```

And place variables inside this segment using:

```
__attribute__((section(".codeflash")))
```

I am using the default linker script.

Thanks.

Comment: For flash? You can define a single `struct` which contains all the global variables as members. You then have complete control over what goes where.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This is something that I have being evaluating. But is there a way to control the order of the variables inside a segment if I do not use a struct?

Comment: I don't think so, the compiler is free to order them by name, or by type, etc. A struct is fairly easy though. If you `typdef` the `struct` and give it a very short name, say `s` then every member it contains is simply appended by `s.` Watch out for padding, but that should be within your control.

Comment: I used your suggestion. This is the cleaner way of doing it. It is also compiler independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the suggestion above to solve the problem:
Added everything to a struct and put this struct inside the section.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say 0x100 bytes from the start of the segment

```
  .codeflash BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    . += 0x100;
    __codeflash_start__ = . ;
    KEEP(*(.codeflash))
    KEEP(*(.codeflash*))
    __codeflash_end__ = . ;    
  }
```